# Does Apple Only Allow Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I'm wondering if I could develop a app using XCode, in a language other than Objective-C such as C, C# or C++. If so, how would I go about doing that? Is there anything special I have to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803774/how-can-i-make-a-c-project-in-xcode

Comment: You can develop application with C or C++ using XCode, but not C#

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use C or C++, and there also exist a "glue" language for mixing C++ with Obj-C code, called Objective-C++.

Objective-C, Objective-C++, C and C++ are also all supported by the XCode IDE.

If you instead want to develop an iOS/OSX app in C#, you may consider [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), but you cannot use XCode. You either have to use Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio.

Comment: Would I need to combine Objective-C and C++, or is there a way to use straight C++?

Comment: For iOS, there's going to need to be at least a little ObjC, though it can be wrapped in something else. For OSX it's not *technically* necessary, but is a very good idea, since the C GUI libraries are on their way out and unsupported in 64 bit.

Comment: My reason for asking it because I'm working on learning to develop apps and I'd like to do it in C or C++ because it will benefit me more in the future if I was to look for a programming job. Should I go straight Obj-C or actually work on figuring it out in C++?

Comment: Objective-C is the language that is meant to be used. While developing apps in C or C++ may be an interesting exercise, it's very likely to be become rather cumbersome very quickly for anything more than basic stuff.

Comment: Note that all C code is also valid ObjC code; you're not giving up any aspect of C by using ObjC :)

Comment: Absolutely true, even though Obj-C exists to make your life easier. The awesome accepted answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c) shows pretty well why you don't wanna use pure C for app development.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella You have it all backwards! C is the future of iOS and Mac development! It *must* be used!

Comment: I hope it's as sarcastic as it gets :D

Answer (score 2):

You can write code using the cross-platform [Qt C++](http://qt.digia.com/) frameworks in Xcode under OS X. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812083/developing-qt-applications-in-xcode) for more.

Answer (score 2):

While it used not to be the case, currently you can practically use any language you want.

Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can employ plain C if you like. Also, Xcode can handle C++ and Objective-C++.

Apart from Xcode, there are many other tools that allow creating apps for iPhone. If you like C#, you can use [Xamarin iOS](http://xamarin.com/monotouch). You can also use LUA with tools such as the [Corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com). If you are into games, you can even use [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/).

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to develop a iOS game in XCode with C++, I'd need to use a game engine that supports C++ correct? Is there anything I'd have to change?

Comment: @user2350763 - You can intermix C++ and Objective-C in the same application, and the standard development environment understands C++ just fine (at least to the extent that anyone/anything understands it).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the standard UI libraries for Mac and iOS are all in Objective-C.  You can use another language but it's going to be significantly more difficult.  If you insist on not using Objective-C as much as possible, then your best bet is to use Obj-C to interact with the standard libraries and another language for all of your program logic.