# Using Xcode To Make QT Applications

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt

I would like to use Xcode as my IDE because I can place buttons, labels etc. while using the Xvim so I can program more efficiently. I used the `qt-unified-mac-x64-2.0.2-1-online` installer, however I cannot see any templates in Xcode V7.1.

How would it be possible to use Xcode to develop QT applications?

This question [Developing QT applications in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812083/developing-qt-applications-in-xcode) does not help because the link which was given is dead.

Comment: "I can place buttons, labels etc" Depending on what you're doing, this would be done either in the qml designer (for Qt Quick controls) or qt designer (for legacy widgets). Both are integrated into Qt Creator. I have no idea what has Xcode to do with any of it, unless you're proposing doing the UI using Apple's technology, and the core code using Qt. Please expand on what labels "etc" do you refer to. Did you try using Qt Creator? It's pretty much as foolproof of an IDE for C++ as it gets.

Comment: @KubaOber What I mean is, with Xcode I can design my UI graphically instead of programmatically. What I want to do is instead of using QT creator, I would like to use Xcode as my IDE since I like it better, I also have XVim (a vim plugin for Xcode. This allows my to type code quicker and more efficiently. This is why I want to use Xcode instead of QT creator.

Comment: Well, if you want to use the XCode-Designer, you can't use Qt. Those have nothing to do with each other. Use Qt with the QtCreator/Designer or use XCode with Swift/Objective-C/...

Comment: *I can design my UI graphically instead of programmatically* You're using Apple technologies then. At that point, given the decent feature set of Cocoa APIs, what's the point of using Qt at all? You're writing a non-portable application, right?

Comment: @KubaOber What I have said I do in Xcode, is for iOS and OS X development. I would like to use this IDE to start programming with QT so I can make cross platform application since they are written in C++.

Comment: You cannot use Xcode for UI design if you wish to use Qt for the UI. As an iOS/OS X programmer you are surely aware of the fact that the output of Xcode's UI design tools is pretty much non-portable and tailored directly to Apple's UI implementation. Qt Creator comes with graphical designers for both widget-based (legacy) UI *and* for QML, so your insistence on using Xcode makes little sense to me. I wrote a rudimentary nib-to-UI converter in the past, and admittedly with enough effort you can do good nib-to-.ui and -.qml conversions, but it's IMHO wasted effort.

Comment: @KubaOber I wasn't sure if there was a QT UI creator plugin for Xcode.

Comment: There isn't one. It wouldn't be very helpful anyway: it's just be the designer plug-in, but used in xcode. Mke sure that you discern various pieces of the puzzle. Qt Creator is an entire IDE, with multiple plug-ins. Internally, it's a completely modular architecture. There are two creator plug-ins that allow UI design. One is the ui designer used to generate legacy (.ui) files. It is available stand-alone as Qt Designer. Another is the Qt Quick Designer used to generate .qml files - it is not available as a stand-alone tool, only as a plugin that comes with Qt Creator.